# Exception in extension code: "CERT_HAS_EXPIRED" error when rejectUnauthorized: false for the agent

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

With the update to VS Code Version: 1.55.0 I see following new behavior:
If I send an POST https request to a server with expired certificate like

```
const agent = https.Agent({rejectUnauthorized: false};
const response = await fetch('https://some-expired-cert-server.com/request', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: {},
  headers,
  agent: agent});
```

I get an exception "request to https://some-expired-cert-server.com/request failed, reason: certificate has expired"

Expected behavior (or what happened before the update to vscode 1.55.0) is that no exception should happen when rejectUnauthorized: false.

Possible workaround is to put:
`process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';`  in the code, but according to many posts this is not advisable.

(I posted that before in vscode github, but was directed here)

Is that something I need to update on the extension side?